# Python 3: Does http.server support ipv6?

Tags: python-3.x, webserver, ipv6

Does `http.server` (`http` being a Python 3.x module) support ipv6? For instance, using this command-line code (which starts a webserver):

```
python -m http.server [port]
```

Comment: Use `netstat -l` to see if it's binding to the port on an IPv6 address. If it is then, "yes it's supported".

Comment: How do you interpret the results? I don't even see the port number I'm connecting to listed there (or any mention of IPv6).

Comment: Also use the `-n` option, does that make the output more useful? IPv6 addresses can be identified by looking different from the IPv4 counterparts - if a server listens to a port on both IPv6 and IPv4 there will be two entries displayed. The listen-all-IPs value for IPv4 is 0.0.0.0 and for IPv6 it is ::0. (And if the port is not displayed after that then the server is not currently running/listening at all.)

Comment: Thanks! I just see the IPv4-style (`tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`). So, I guess that means it doesn't support IPv6. You should condense all this into an answer so I can accept it, if you want.

Comment: The tornado module works for IPv6 with a webserver in Python (I saw that it did, but I tested it with your method, and it shows up twice, in both formats.)

Comment: But it isn't an answer :( It just says that it isn't currently listening on IPv6; not that it can't. There might be an option, etc., or it might simply be the network interface isn't setup for IPv6.

Comment: I think you're right, actually. I looked at the source code to `client.py` which is part of the `http` module, and I see references to IPv6 and how to handle it. So, I suppose it must be possible, somehow.

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work. The underlying code obviously supports it. Time to file a feature request.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it does.  When defining your server, do it like this, as seen [here](https://gist.github.com/akorobov/7903307).

```
import socket
from http.server import HTTPServer

class HTTPServerV6(HTTPServer):
    address_family = socket.AF_INET6
```

and then listen like this:

```
server = HTTPServerV6(('::', 8080), MyHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Sadly it seems difficult to make the built-in HTTP server handle both IPv6 and IPv4 connections.

Comment: An IPv6 stack handles IPv4 connections as long as the passive socket isn't bound to a specific v6 address (!= in6addr_any, an empty string of "::") or the option IPv6_ONLY is set.

Comment: In case anyone is trying to replicate the default `python -m http.server` behavior of serving the current working directory, you can do that by changing two lines. `from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`
and
`server = HTTPServerV6(('::', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)`

Answer (score 56):

Starting with Python 3.8, `python -m http.server` supports IPv6 (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html) and [bug report with implementation history](https://bugs.python.org/issue24209)).

To listen on all all available interfaces:

```
python -m http.server --bind ::
```

Python 3.8 is was released on [2019-10-14](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/).

Comment: For the port do you just put it at the end, like `python -m http.server --bind :: 8100`?

Answer (score 10):

There is a patch to allow IPv6 bind in `http.server` in Python 3. I tried it, finding it works on my laptop.
Please visit https://bugs.python.org/issue24209 for more info.
Or just do as following:

Add the lines after `+` to the file `/your/path/to/python/Lib/http/server.py`.
Please note lines without `+` are the original code of `server.py`.

```
    server_address = (bind, port)

+   if ':' in bind:
+       ServerClass.address_family = socket.AF_INET6
+        
    HandlerClass.protocal_version = protocol    
    httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
```

Then try:

```
python -m http.server -b *your-ipv6-addr* *your-port*
```

Comment: You could extend HttpServer instead of hacking your Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 3 version (until 3.8) of [Oliver Bock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621449/6078370) does look like this:

myserver.py:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import socket

class HTTPServerV6(HTTPServer):
    address_family = socket.AF_INET6

server = HTTPServerV6(('::', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Modifying your internal Python 3 files like [Edward Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112683/6078370) seems rather extreme.